# Jquery Validate - Input Mask Conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, mask

I have a form that uses jquery validate and the form validates on submit and on blur (onfucusout).  Some of my fields have masks using the jquery mask plug in.  The mask will place something like this in the field (---)---/---- when it comes into focus.  When the user clicks out of this field the (---)---/---- disappears.  My problem is that although the field is left black it is throwing the validation error thinking that the user has typed in (---)---/---- instead of just leaving it blank.

My first thought was to put a delay on the validate so that it validates after (---)---/---- disappears.  My question is how do have set the validate to delay so that it evaluates the field after the characters are gone?  If this isn't the right fix can someone help me fix this issue.

Again i think it is caused because the validation is triggering before the mask characters are going away.  I need it to validate after the masked place holders disappear.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The way I addressed this problem.

**Input Mask in my case :** "(999) 999-9999"

**For my test example i did the following :**

(1) The first thing i did was determined what characters were being generated in my DOM.
e.g. 
using the below code in FireBug Console.

$('#MyPhoneNumberID').keydown(function(){
console.log($(this).val())

In my case it was spitting out the following (**_)** -___

(2) The work around I used was to update my regular expression(for phone) and include the mask as part of the regular expression 
e.g. "(**_)** -___" OR correct typed in phone numbers was allowed.

**Regular Expression used :** 
"^(?:+)?(1)?(?:\s*(?:-|.|()?\s*)?(\d{3}|_{3}|\s{3})(?:\s*(?:-|.|))?\s*)?(\d{3}|_{3}|\s{3})(?:\s*(?:-|.)?\s*)?(\d{4}|_{4}|\s{4})$"

Hope this helps!